# How to use ambient route values in link generation in ASP.NET Core 8 after their removal in in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

Using ASP.NET Core 8 Razor pages, I would like to be able to generate a link to a page that requires custom route parameters without manually supplying them every time.

An example is below, the `IPageContextAccessor` accesses the current pages route values and then I have to add them to the outbound route manually.

```
# Link page
@page "/org/{org}/projects/{project}"
@inject IPageContextAccessor Context
@model Details

<a asp-page="/Translate/Index" asp-route-org="@Context.Organisation.Name" asp-route-project="@Context.Project.Name">
    Translate
</a>
```

```
# Target Page
@page "/org/{org}/projects/{project}/translate"
...
```

Previously, in ASP.NET Core 3.1, it was possible to use the 'ambient' route values in link generation, which led to much less boilerplate code:

```
@page "/org/{org}/projects/{project}"
@model Details

<a asp-page="/Translate/Index">
    Translate
</a>
```

This functionality was removed per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#changes-to-link-generation

Do I have to somehow rebuild this functionality using a custom `UrlHelper` or `TagHelper`, or is there some mechanism to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom UrlHelper like below:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string LinkWithAmbientValues(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string pageName, object routeValues = null)
    {
        var currentRouteValues = urlHelper.ActionContext.RouteData.Values;
        var newRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        foreach (var item in currentRouteValues)
        {
            if (!newRouteValues.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            {
                newRouteValues.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }

        return urlHelper.Page(pageName, newRouteValues);
    }
}
```

Then apply it in your link page:

```
<a href="@Url.LinkWithAmbientValues("/Translate/Index")">Translate</a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with a tag helper? it might make the solution a bit cleaner?

Comment: Hi @PeterKneale, of course you can. You can use it like `<a asp-customTag="/Translate/Index"></a>`, but I think it seems no difference with urlhelper?